# How do I skip the packaging step when building a Windows Store app using MSBuild?

Tags: uwp, msbuild, windows-10-universal, appveyor

I am currently trying to set up continuous integration for my Windows Store application using AppVeyor. The problem I am facing is that the build fails because the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file is missing. This is the detailed error message (`error APPX0002`):

```
(_ValidateAppxPackage target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2625,5): error APPX0002: Task 'ValidateAppxPackage' failed. Could not find file 'C:\projects\...\<PROJECTNAME>\Package.StoreAssociation.xml'. [C:\projects\...\<PROJECTNAME>\<PROJECTNAME>.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2625,5): error APPX0002:  [C:\projects\...\<PROJECTNAME>\<PROJECTNAME>.csproj]
```

During my research I found this [site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108554/build-error-logs-do-not-show-package-validation-er.html), which says that this error occurs because of the step which creates the app packages and that it's skipped when using Visual Studio, which I can approve because it works on machines that don't have the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` file.

Is there any way to skip this step when using MSBuild, respectively AppVeyor?

---

So I've found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2014/02/17/using-msbuild-to-build-windows-store-application-without-signing-the-appxpackage/) site which suggested to set the parameter `AppxPackageSigningEnabled` to `false`. Unfortunately, that did not help. The command I'm currently using is the following:

```
msbuild "C:\projects\...\<PROJECTNAME>.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false /p:AppxBundle=Never /verbosity:normal /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"
```

Comment: What's the build command that you're using in AppVeyor? And have you directly tried to use msbuild to build your project to see if you can package successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see the edited question for the build command. Next I will try to use MSBuild directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem is actually quite simple yet it took me several hours to figure it out, which doesn't make me proud. Now I would like to share my solution:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /p:AppxPackage=false /verbosity:minimal
```

Using this command the build works just fine. The important parameter here is **`/p:AppxPackage=false`**, which will skip the creation of the AppxPackage. This is exactly what I wanted since signing would not work because the `StoreKey.pfx` file is missing and I cannot provide the key because the application itself is open-source.

Comment: You actually can provide a key using [secure file](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/secure-files/) or make `.pfx` password-protected and keep password as a [secure variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables). Also I don't think `/t:Rebuild` makes sense in AppVeyor environment as it is fresh repo clone on fresh VM

Comment: Good point. I will change it to `/t:Build` and update my answer. And thanks for the tip regarding the secure file since this solves my other problem.

Comment: @turbolocust Brilliant. Prevented me from spending hours of my own time trying to solve this same issue.

Comment: "...it took me several hours to figure it out, which doesn't make me proud." <--
Don't beat yourself up @turbolocust; this stuff may end up being a simple command but the documentation around this stuff offers very little help to engineers. Good documentation discusses _why_ options are available, wheras all the documentation I see only describes _what_ options are available.